# jQuery: Clone element by choosing SELECT OPTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have a SELECT where I choose how many cars the user has. After that he/she will get the same amount of DIVs with INPUTs to descripe what models etc.

How do I clone the DIV with the containing INPUTs, with the SELECT?

Comment: Please share some code. Or at give a link to jsfiddle at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the general idea...

```
$('select#cars').change(function() {
   // Get number of cars chosen
   var carsCount = $(this).val(),
       // Get a reference to the first input group so we can clone it
       carInput = $('#car-inputs div:first');

   // Clone per number chosen
   for (var i = 0; i < carsCount; i++) {
       // Insert clone after original.
       // IRL, you probably need to do some preprocessing on it first.
       carInput.clone().insertAfter(carInput);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I works great. However if I choose 4 (by a mistake) and then 3 afterwards, it adds 3 more. Can I modify it so it displays the correct amount regardless of how many times I change it?

Comment: @Kenneth The *easy* way would be to select all but the first `#car-inputs select:gt(0)` and `remove()`. However, to keep the text in there, you could set `i` in the loop to be equal to the current `length` of the elements.

Comment: I don't get it. Where would you use this? I would like to count this for IDs or NAMEs as well. I guess I could use :gt as well here?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the clone can help you : http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am familiar with Clone(), I wasn't however clear about how to combine that with a select option... :-)